# Spivak Calculus chapter 2 problem 5b - what's the intuition?

Tags: proof-explanation, intuition

I am able to solve, but I don't understand the intuition behind the framing of the problem and therefore don't understand what I did.

Derive the result: $1+r+r^2+...+r^n = \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$

by setting $S=1+r+r^2+...+r^n$ and $rS = r(1+r+r^2+...+r^n)$, and solving the two equations for S.

So, we have:

$rS = r+r^2+r^{n+1}$

$rS = 1 + r+r^2+...+r^n + r^{n+1} -1$

$rS = S + r^{n+1} -1$

$rS-S = r^{n+1} -1$

$S-rS = 1-r^{n+1}$

$S(1-r) = 1-r^{n+1}$

$S = \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$

My question: what is the general concept behind the idea to bring in $rS$, and why does that work here?  I don't see what is going on.

Comment: Multiplication of a geometric series by $r$ shifts terms one to the right. Now a lot of stuff in the middle cancels!

Comment: One intuition is the following: verify that $1111=(10^5-1)/9$. Find a formula for $n$ $1$s in a row. Generalize to other bases.

Comment: The whole point of that approach was to derive: $$rS = S + r^{n+1} -1,$$ after which the $S$ variables can be combined on the LHS.  For what it's worth an easier approach is to use Induction, proving that if the assertion is true for $n$, then the assertion must also be true for $(n+1).$

Comment: Here is a perhaps more satisfying proof. We want a closed form for $1+r+\dots +r^n$. Recall that this term appears in the factorization $r^{n+1}-1= (r-1)(1+r+\dots+r^n)$.

Answer (score -1):

We want to get a closed Form for the geometric sum

$S:=1+r+...+r^n$

A good try is, to get some sort of relation between the sum and the ratio r of the arithmetic progression. Therefore exploring $rS$ is intuitive.
Then we notice that we actually can express $rS$ in terms of S, giving us the wanted relation:

$rS=r+...+r^{n+1}=S-1+r^{n+1}\implies...$